# Are there any benefits in levelling up a spawn before evolving?

Tags: blood-brothers

When evolving a familiar, I know that having the seed at max level will result in a 10% stats transfer as opposed to a 5%, but is there any benefit in having the spawn at max level before evolving?

So lets say I evolve the following:

```
Lvl 1 Spawn
Lvl 40 Seed
```

and:

```
Lvl 40 Spawn
Lvl 40 Seed
```

Will the second evolution be any better off that the first (assuming the same familiar type is used for all)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The spawn will still get the same amount from the seed   so in other words No  you do not need to max out the lvl of the spawn to get max stats from seed

Answer (score 3):

There is a benefit you get for using a higher level spawn, and that benefit is the evolution you receive keeps the current level, and current skill level of the spawn.

IE: [[Spawn] Slime I (lvl 40) Skill - Coin Barrage (lvl 20)] + {{Seed} Slime I (lvl40) Skill - Coin barrage (lvl 1) = Slime II (lvl 40) Skill - Coin Barrage (lvl 20)

Where if you did the same evolution but with a spawn at level 1, and skill level 1, the evolution you receive would have the same level and skill level.

IE: [[Spawn] Slime I (lvl 1) Skill - Coin Barrage (lvl 1)] + {{Seed} Slime I (lvl40) Skill - Coin barrage (lvl 1) = Slime II (lvl 1) Skill - Coin Barrage (lvl 1)

Hope this helps! 
-Swag

Answer (score 2):

In theory, with a familiar with four possible stars, leveling 8 would be ideal to get a perfect 1. (IE evolve into 4 2 stars, 2 3 stars, and 1 four star.) Maybe the best possible is doing this while also leaving the spawn of the end result at level 1? You'd have to really want a damn good familiar to do it this way though.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still experimenting, but I think by using a lower level spawn and a max level seed you get a resulting evolution with greater potential benefits of the evolution and the 10% stat gain from the seed. That is if you use a low level spawn then that spawn will be gain a bonus to its stats at a lower level, thus the resulting evolution will have more "room" (levels to be gained) to improve upon stats that have already been maximized. Rather than having an evolution with stats determined by previous levels of the the shitty spawn it was before. Assuming the evolved card grows faster this would work.

eg. lv 70/70 medusa II + lv 70/70 medusa II = lv 70/99 gorgon (with 70 levels of stats determined by medusa 2)

VS : lv1 1/70 medusa II + lv 70/70 medusa II = lv 1/99 gorgon (only 1 level of medusa II's stats, so 98 more levels of gorgon growth rather than medusa II's + max stat benefit of max level medusa II seed.)

Comment: An interesting theory, it would be good if you could back this up with some hard figures though

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are keeping the spawn's level and adding 5% or 10% stat of the seeds. So you can increase level before or after revolution.